# Convert a np array to its binary ascii value and write it to a file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file, ascii

I have a binary np array below:

```
arr = [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 1. 1.]
```

I would like to convert them to the binary sequences stored as its ascii value of each element to a .bin file (the output file name is 'test.bin').
For example, zero's ascii value is 48 and its corresponding binary form is: 00110000. If there is a zero in the np array, there should be a corresponding 00110000 in the bin file
I tried to use the code below:

```
buffer_string = ''.join(str(x) for x in arr.astype(int))
with open("test.bin", "wb") as f:
    for x in buffer_string:
        f.write(bytes(ord(x)))
```

But the outputs are all zeros. Could you please give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly should  be the resulting contents of the file in this example?

Comment: For example, zero's ascii value is 48 and its corresponding binary form is: 00110000. If there is a zero in the np array, there should be a corresponding 00110000 in the bin file

Comment: Did you try `f.write(buffer_string)`?

Comment: Sure I tried. But I got the following error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Then you either need to open the file with `'w'`, or explicitly encode the string as ASCII. I don't think it makes a difference in this case (since `'0'` and `'1'` have the same encoding in ASCII and UTF-8 afaik).

Comment: I believe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850103/writing-to-files-in-ascii-with-python3-not-utf8

Comment: I will try it. Thanks!